# Uploading retrieved files in a FTP server to mongodb collection using spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, file, ftp, spring-integration

I have implemented a springboot application to retrieve files from an FTP server and to download them into my local directory.

Following is the code which I used to do that.

```
@Configuration
public class FTPConfiguration {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpMGET")
    @Bean
    public FtpOutboundGateway getFiles() {
        FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(sf(), "mget", "payload");
        gateway.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        gateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("./downloads/"));
        gateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE_IF_MODIFIED);
        gateway.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
        gateway.setOutputChannelName("fileResults");
        return gateway;
    }

   @Bean
    public MessageChannel fileResults() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        channel.addInterceptor(tap());
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public WireTap tap() {
        return new WireTap("logging");
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "logging")
    @Bean
    public LoggingHandler logger() {
        LoggingHandler logger = new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO);
        logger.setLogExpressionString("'Files:' + payload");
        return logger;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("localhost");
        sf.setPort(2121);
        sf.setUsername("anonymous");
        sf.setPassword("");
        return sf;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "ftpMGET", defaultReplyChannel = "fileResults")
    public interface GateFile {

        List<File> mget(String directory);

    }
}
```

Now I need to upload these files to my MongoDB automatically, when I run this program.
Can anyone please help me or guide me the steps I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look into a MongoDB support in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-outbound-channel-adapter

You probably need to think how to make some POJO from files of that MGET result and send it to that MongoDB channel adapter for storing as documents in some collection.